# One to Many Database field uniqueness rule in YII

Tags: yii

I have a table. Lets say we have a userid of 23, which corresponds to various roles that the user might hold: scientist, researcher and developer. ID's respectively: 2,8,9.

[image]

So, userid can be duplicated but roleid as it relates to userid is unique. Note that if there are more then 1 users I want it so that roles can be duplicated (unique to the user, duplicated across different users) such as: 
[image]

In Yii, under rules of the model you can create a rule to do uniqueness. I want the RoleID field to be unique for that user. So if user x has role y, it won't add role y again (creating duplicates).

here's the schema:

[image]

Comment: i think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10435307/720508) will help you

Comment: It did. Should we mark for deletion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii validation rule - unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10432591/yii-validation-rule-unique)